# Schematic diagram with switches

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuitikz, circuits

[image: Diagram]

I want to do this diagram in latex. I know how to draw rectangles and arrows (basic tikz user) but doing it symmetrically such that the arrow head is in the center of the box consumes a lot of time (usually need to do it on paper first specifying all the lengths). Is there a faster way of doing this kind of diagrams? Also if you can help with any part of this diagram I can complete the rest. Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far -- you may like to upload a MWE

Comment: Both tikz and circuitikz have libraries of predefined circuit components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find yourself doing a lot of manual calculation for maintaining symmetry, I have two suggestions for you:

1. learn to use correctly relative coordinates, `coordinate` and anchors;
2. learn to use the `calc` Ti*k*Z library (not needed here, but...).

One way to build your diagram is the following one (could be compacted, but I didn't want to use tricks or other similar things --- the code should be straightforward).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(A) to[rmeterwa] ++(3,0) coordinate(B);
    % circuitikz manual page 105
    \node [cute spdt up arrow, anchor=in](sw-r) at (B){};
    \node [cute spdt up arrow, anchor=in, xscale=-1](sw-l) at (A){};
    \draw [dashed] (sw-l-in) -- (sw-l-out 2);
    \draw [dashed] (sw-r-in) -- (sw-r-out 2);
    \draw (sw-l.out 1) -- ++(-2,0);
    \draw (sw-l.out 2) to[generic, name=G] ++(-2,0);
    \node at (G.center) {D};
    % circuitikz manual page 71
    % put the adder midway between the switch and ++(2,0)
    \draw (sw-r.out 1) ++(1,0) node[adder, circuitikz/blocks/scale=0.5](ADD){} ++(1,0) coordinate(Aend);
    \draw (sw-r.out 1) -- (ADD.w) node[inputarrow]{} (ADD.e) -- (Aend) node[inputarrow]{};
    \draw (ADD.n) node[inputarrow, rotate=-90]{} -- ++(0,0.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer....perfect!

Comment: This solution is a neat but I still need to consult the manual to understand these apparently predefined names before I can modify the diagram at will. Thanks you! Very nice!

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be like that --- I mean, reading the manual. Otherwise, the time I and the other developers spent *writing* it would be a little pity...

Comment: @Rmano, yes. Im getting familiar. My changes have finally started compiling XD. I do not want to post another question. Maybe you can help. I want to draw a matrix keypad (letss say 4x6) and connect resistors to each element. Is there a quick way to create such a grid? and can each of the elements be instantiated?

Comment: @Duns, not sure to understand you (especially when you talk about "instantiating" elements) ... there is a `matrix` syntax in Ti*k*Z, but you can do that probably with `foreach` (page 1001 :-)  of the Ti*k*Z manual.). But it's better ro post another question, just this time show where you got stuck and let people start from there in helping you.

Answer (score 5):

A pstricks solution with the `pst-circ` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1)(6.5,2.5)
\sffamily\psset{dash=4pt 3pt, linewidth=1pt, arrowinset=0, linejoin=1}%, 
\SpecialCoor
\pnodes{A}(0,0)(-1.5,0)(1.5,0)
\pnodes{B}(-5,0.75)(-2.5,0.75)(2.5,0.75)(6.4,0.75)
\pnodes{C}(-5,-0.75)(-2.5,-0.75)(2.5,-0.75)
\pnodes(0,0){O}(4.45,2.5){C}
\pcline(B0)(B1)
\resistor[labeloffset=0](C0)(C1){D}
\Ucc(A1)(A2){}
{\psset{linewidth=0.8pt}\psline{->}(0.9;-120)(0.9;60)
\psarc{->}(A1){0.75}{110}{170}\psarcn{->}(A2){0.75}{70}{10}}
{\psset{linewidth=1.5pt}\pcline{-*}(A1)(B1)\pcline[linestyle=dashed]{o-*}(A1)(C1)%
\pcline{-*}(A2)(B2)\pcline[linestyle=dashed]{o-*}(A2)(C2)}
\Ucc[labeloffset=0](B2)(B3){\Large\bfseries+}
\psline{->}(C)(4.45,1.25)\psline{->}(B2)(3.96,0.75)\psline{->}(5,0.75)(6.5,0.75)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice :-)

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation, @Sebastiano.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Bernard.